# Concatenate two pandas data frames together (in python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, stock

I am working on a simple trading also and need some help with concatenating to data frames together. Until my now my approach does't work.

My code is the following:

Connect to quantle API

```
 quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

Ticker symbols

```
ticker = ['FSE/ZO1_X',"FSE/WAC_X"]
```

Create a panel object with quotes from panda -> create a pandas DataFrame

```
 df = quandl.get(ticker, start_date='2017-01-01', end_date='2017-11-03')
```

Slicing the close prices for each stock out of the panel data set

```
close1 = df['FSE/ZO1_X - Close']
close2 = df['FSE/WAC_X - Close']
```

Concatenate the two data frames together - THIS STEP DOESN'T WORK

```
 close = pd.concat(close1,close2)
```

The type of close1 and close 2 is pandas.core.series.Series.

How can I put close1 and close2 together, so that the index is the date and I have two additional columns with the close prices of stock 1 (close1) and stock 2 (close2) - similar like an ordinary excel sheet.

Comment: That was quite loud.

Comment: Need `[]` like `close = pd.concat([close1,close2])` ?

Comment: Explanation of how [`.concat()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) works.

Answer (score 5):

```
close = pd.concat([close1, close2], axis=1)
```

should do it.

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])
t = pd.Series([11,12,13,14,15])
s = pd.concat([s,t], axis=1)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
   0   1
0  1  11
1  2  12
2  3  13
3  4  14
4  5  15
```

Comment: Corrected the output. If you do axis = 1, you get the two series appended one after the other.

Comment: Also, if you want an explanation, you would find https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html very helpful!